# Android NDK: calling java method from JNI C class

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have JNI method where I am trying to call Java method. Here is my JNI code

```
void DummySink::afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                  struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned /*durationInMicroseconds*/) {

     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "RTSP", "Frame: %c", propRec->sPropBytes);
     jmethodID mid;
     jclass handlerClass = env9->FindClass("ob/android/Stream");
     if (handlerClass == NULL) {
         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "RTSP-Error", "Class");
     }
     mid = env9->GetMethodID(handlerClass, "onResponse", "([B)V");
     if (mid == NULL) {
         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "RTSP-Error", "Method");
     }

     jbyteArray jbArray = env9->NewByteArray((int)propRec->sPropLength);
     env9->SetByteArrayRegion(jbArray, 0, (int)propRec->sPropLength, (jbyte*)propRec->sPropBytes);

     //jobject theClass = env9->FindClass("ob/android/Stream");

     env9->CallVoidMethod(handlerClass, mid, jbArray);

}
```

Here is the Java code that I have

```
public void onResponse(byte[] str) 
    { 
        Log.v("Response", "Java");
    }
```

I am receiving following crash

```
03-08 16:01:05.915: W/dalvikvm(17552): JNI WARNING: can't call Lob/android/Stream;.onResponse on instance of Ljava/lang/Class;
03-08 16:01:05.915: W/dalvikvm(17552):              in Lob/android/Stream;.stream:()V (CallVoidMethodV)
```

After applying Mah's answer, here is the exception I am receiving

```
03-08 16:40:20.646: W/dalvikvm(4076): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
03-08 16:40:20.646: W/dalvikvm(4076):              in Lob/android/Stream;.stream:()V (NewByteArray)
03-08 16:40:20.646: W/dalvikvm(4076): Pending exception is:
03-08 16:40:20.646: I/dalvikvm(4076): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='onResponse' signature='([B)V' in class Lob/android/Stream;
03-08 16:40:20.646: I/dalvikvm(4076):   at ob.android.Stream.stream(Native Method)
03-08 16:40:20.646: I/dalvikvm(4076):   at ob.android.Stream.<init>(Stream.java:28)
03-08 16:40:20.654: I/dalvikvm(4076):   at ob.android.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:203)
```

Now onResponse method is static.

Comment: You must check for and handle exceptions after any JNI call that can throw an exception.  `CallVoidMethod` being a prime example.  See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#exceptions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Java method is an instance method (not static), but your native code isn't referring to any specific instance of `ob.android.Stream` to call `onResponse()` for.

When calling `CallVoidMethod()`, the first parameter is to be the instance (object) you're running the method against, not the class itself. The class itself would be used if you were using `CallStaticVoidMethod()`.

Comment: Any chance of getting a little more detail when I change to.. jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(obj, "playA", "()V"); I see... error: invalid conversion from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jclass {aka _jclass*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Jackie `GetMethodId()` wants the _class_ to get the method id from, not an _object_ as you appear to be using. If you don't already have the class for that object available, you can get it from that _obj_ by using `GetObjectClass()`

Comment: Correction: The first argument to CallVoidMethod must be the java environment to run the method in.

Comment: @EvanLeis if the calling environment were `C` you would be correct. Since it's `C++` though, the java environment is not the first parameter because it's the object the message is being called against, as in `env->CallVoidMethod()`. You can tell that `C++` is the language at play here from the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more solution to the NoSuchMethodError problem, that although might not be the case here, might save some of you a lot of hours of debugging.

For me, there was a proguard config file that I had to edit. Otherwise all non-static java methods that aren't called in the java code, get optimized out and the native C++ code isn't able to find them.