# Cannot use CallVoidMethod from another object

Tags: java-native-interface

There are two class A, B
m_Class, m_MethodID are not NULL..
But system will crash after call env->CallVoidMethod, Why?

```
public Class A extends Activity {
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        B BClass = new B();
        BClass.setFunction(this, "testFunc");
    }
    public void testFunc() {
        Log.e("", "Test");
    }
}

public Class B {

    public native void setFunction(Object caller, String method);
}
```

-------------JNI-------------

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_B_setFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject clsCaller, jstring sMethod) {

    string sMethodName = jstring2str(env, sMethod);
    jclass m_Class = env->GetObjectClass(clsCaller);
    jmethodID m_MethodID = env->GetMethodID(m_Class, sMethodName.c_str(), "()V");

    env->CallVoidMethod(m_Class, m_MethodID);
}
```

Comment: sMethodName should be released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had resolve this issue..
I refer to this page [Android NDK: calling java method from JNI C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292432/android-ndk-calling-java-method-from-jni-c-class)
and modify the code in JNI

from

```
env->CallVoidMethod(m_Class, m_MethodID);
```

to

```
env->CallVoidMethod(clsCaller, m_MethodID);
```

Because CallVoidMethod is trigger by instance(clsCaller) not class(m_Class)